# Cannot find the right regex for rename

Tags: regular-expression, rename

I have some TV shows stored on my Ubuntu server and I could rename them all, so Kodi can recognise them, exept one:

First Episode, first Season:

```
Name - S01E001 - Title part1
Name - S01E001 - Title part2
Name - S01E001 - Title part3
```

First Episode, second Season:

```
Name - S02E020 - Title part1
Name - S02E020 - Title part2
Name - S02E020 - Title part3
```

So Kodi thinks the second video is S02E20, but it is S02E01.
The six files should be after the renaming:

First Episode, first Season:

```
Name - S01E001.1 - Title
Name - S01E001.2 - Title
Name - S01E001.3 - Title
```

First Episode, second Season:

```
Name - S02E001.1 - Title
Name - S02E001.2 - Title
Name - S02E001.3 - Title
```

I know, that there are many related questions here, but none fits this pattern and nearly noone explains his solution. The manpage of `rename` doesn't help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression match `/^(.*) - (.*) - (.*) part([0-9]+)/` stuffs the name, episode indicator, title and part number in groups which you can then use as `$1` through `$4` in the replacement text.

```
rename 's/^(.*) - (.*) - (.*) part([0-9]+)/$1 - $2.$4 - $3/' *
```

Anything after the `part1` part, such as a file extension, is left unchanged.

If you want to modify the capture groups, use the `e` modifier at the end of the `s/…/…/` expression. In `s/REGEX/REPLACEMENT/e`, the `REPLACEMENT` part is a Perl expression, not a string with variable interpolation. In a Perl expression, use the `.` operator to concatenate strings. For example, if you want to subtract 1 from the part number:

```
rename 's/^(.*) - (.*) - (.*) part([0-9]+)/"$1 - $2." . ($4-1) . " - $3"/e' *
```

Comment: Great answer, but one thing is missing. I have modified the regex, but need some help: ` rename -n 's/^(.*) - (S02)(E)([0-9]+) - (.*) part([0-9]+)/$1 - $2$3$4.$6 - $5/' *` does the same. Now I have to lower `$4`. How can I do this? The Bash way (`$((42-21))`) is not working

Comment: @Motte001 See my edit.